# When to decide to call R functions with bracket vs without bracket

Tags: r

I am learning R.
Why is that sometime a function in R is called with brackets like say
`myfunction()` vs sometimes it is called without `myfunction`

How do I know when to call with bracket vs without?

I see a lot of function calls in tidyverse without a bracket

Comment: Hello, it depends if the function needs to have the parameters specified or not. 
Example, paste0("character1","character2") needs the parameters
But if you use sapply(1:5,sqrt), you are sending the values 1...5 to the sqrt() function

Comment: @AugtPelle ... `java ... is the language that was used to create R in the first place`? I've not heard that before, and find it hard to believe: S was first written around 1976, and the open-source version R was started in 1992 and released in 1995 (loose refs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language) and https://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2020/07/the-history-of-r-updated-for-2020.html); whereas Java was released in 1995 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)). S is influenced by C, APL, PPL, and Fortran; R by Common Lisp, Scheme, and (of course) S.

Comment: @AJAY: When you express a function as `myfunction`, you are referencing the object, not calling it. When you express a function as `myfunction(...)`, the function is evaluated with any arguments you pass. (And a common naming convention: `( )` are parens or parentheses; `[ ]` are brackets or square brackets; and less-well-cemented, `{ }` are braces, or curly braces or curly brackets or perhaps other names.)

Comment: Could you provide an example of one such case you have seen? I suspect it is because of the `magrittr` [pipe](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/). In that case `x %>% sum` is the same as `sum(x)` and `x %>% sum()`. Note that not writing the brackets is [bad practice](https://style.tidyverse.org/pipes.html?q=magrittr#no-arguments) according to the tidyverse styleguide.

Comment: Continuing, not every object is a `function`, so while one can do both `mean` (returns the un-evaluated function) and `mean(1,2,3)` (evaluated with arguments), one can do `mtcars` (class `data.frame`, an object with data) but cannot do `mtcars()`, since calling data as a function does not have meaning here.

Comment: But lastly, DonaldSeinen stole my thunder with the last salient point: when used with `%>%`, the pipe operator looks at the RHS (where with `mtcars %>% myfunction`, `mtcars` is the LHS and `myfunction` is the RHS) and automatically calls it as a function, the `()` are *inferred*. I agree with DonaldSeinen that it is a bad practice to leave off `()`, for many reasons, many of which are subjective and/or hypothetical. It really should always be written as `mtcars %>% myfunction()` or perhaps more verbosely `mtcars %>% myfunction(.)`.

Comment: @AugtPelle That’s simply *completely* wrong. (a) R wasn’t created using Java, and predates it. (b) Unlike R, Java *is* strongly typed. (c) This has nothing to do with strong typing. (d) This is *completely* logical, and governed by consistent rules.

Comment: @AJAY Please provide more details. As it is, your question cannot be answered because it seems to be based on a false premise (Donald’s comment notwithstanding).

Comment: Sorry ! I meant C, not Java !!!! My apologies.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I think he is simply talking about functions that are passed as arguments to other functions / the pipe without being called directly using `f(x)` syntax. I'm guessing it's a dupe but I can't find one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In R you can think of a function as an object. The object has two components: the arguments that the function accepts (called the *formals*), and the actual code inside the curly brackets called the function *body*.

For example, lets define a simple function called `f`:

```r
f <- function(x) { x + 1 }
```

If we just type `f` with no parentheses into the console, we can see the formals and body of this new object `f`:

```
f
#> function(x) { x + 1 }
#> <bytecode: 0x000001f8dc3e3f50>
```

We can see its formals separately by doing:

```r
formals(f)
#> $x
```

And its body by doing:

```r
body(f)
#> {
#>     x + 1
#> }
```

So the function is really just an object. But normally we want to *use* the function to do some calculation for us. We use a function by *calling* it. That means that we give some values to the arguments in the formals, and these are used in the calculations inside the body.

When we *call*  a function, we normally do it by putting our variables in parentheses after the function's name:

```r
f(1)
#> [1] 2
```

But this isn't the only way to call a function. We can give R the function name and the arguments we wish to pass to it in `do.call` for example:

```r
do.call(f, list(x = 1))
#> [1] 2
```

We can even build the call as a list of function name and argument, then ask R to evaluate it directly:

```
eval(as.call(list(f, x = 1)))
#> [1] 2
```

But the most common way is to simply put parentheses with the arguments after our function name. The R parser recognizes this as meaning "call that function with these arguments". Note that the function doesn't even need a name for this to work:

```r
(function(x){ x + 1 })(1)
#> [1] 2
```

The reason we sometimes see functions without parentheses after is down to the fact that functions are objects which can themselves be passed to other functions. For example, suppose we have this function:

```r
call_func_with_data <- function(func, data) {
  do.call(func, list(data))
}
```

I can pass any function I want into it and it will try to call it with the data I pass:

```r
z <- 1:10

call_func_with_data(mean, z)
#> [1] 5.5
call_func_with_data(min, z)
#> [1] 1
call_func_with_data(max, z)
#> [1] 10
call_func_with_data(f, z)
#>  [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

Note that I have used all these functions without parentheses. This is in essence what is happening inside tidyverse and apply-type functions where you see function names without parentheses after them. It is also what is happening when you use the syntax:

```r
1 %>% f
#> [1] 2
```

These are just different ways of calling the function.

<sup>Created on 2022-01-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

There are really only two possibilities:

1. Call the function by putting parentheses after it, e.g. `sqrt(4)`
2. Pass the function itself to another function which in turn invokes it.  In this case we are not calling the function but passing it on as an argument to another function. e.g.

   ```
    sapply(1:4, sqrt) # pass sqrt to sapply which invokes it repeatedly
    do.call(sqrt, list(4))  # pass sqrt to do.call which in turn invokes it
   ```

### infix

There are also infix functions such as `+` (which are placed between their arguments) and unary functions which are placed before their argument but these are just different on the surface and are actually the same underneath. For example, these are the same.

```
   1+2
   `+`(1, 2)
```

and these are the same

```
!TRUE
`!`(TRUE)
```

### pipes

There are also pipes but these just manipulate the syntax so that either of these are conceptually the same.

```
 sqrt(4)
 4 |> sqrt()
```

The magrittr package also has pipes so any of these are conceptually the same.  Here it is passing `sqrt` or `sqrt()` to the `%>%` infix function which then interprets it as if it were the first `sqrt` line below.

```
library(magrittr)

sqrt(4)
4 %>% sqrt
4 %>% sqrt()
```

Comment: thanks, GREAT Explanation!