# purrr::reduce(full_join()) does not work: why?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I am having a hard time trying to understand why this syntax for `purrr::reduce()` isn't equivalent:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# Reprex
a <- list()
for(i in 1:10) a[[i]] <- mtcars

# These ones all work
reduce(a, full_join)
reduce(a, ~full_join(.x, .y))
reduce(a, \(x,y) full_join(x, y))

# This one doesn't 
reduce(a, full_join())
```

```
> reduce(a, full_join())
Error in UseMethod("full_join") :
  no applicable method for 'full_join' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

What is the difference between calling `full_join` vs `full_join()`?

Thank you in advance

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70907048/when-to-decide-to-call-r-functions-with-bracket-vs-without-bracket

Comment: A short translation of the above linked question to this specific case: passing just `full_join` provides the function _object_ which `reduce` can then use to construct a call. Passing `full_join()` is itself a function call, which R will attempt to evaluate when it evaluates the arguments to `reduce`, so at some point you're telling R to literally run the function `full_join()` with no arguments, which generates the error you see.

Comment: Thank you both, this is clearer now. I think the main issue was trying to understand that `full_join` is treated like a function object and it doesn't call the function directly